# How to contain text from breaking elements?

Tags: php, html, css, line, line-breaks

This is a very simple question, but embarrassingly enough I am not sure how to implement this :\

I have div elements with text boxes inside them for users to write comments,replies etc... Very standard concept. The div that contains the text is a certain width. If someone where to write something with out using any spaces, instead of breaking down a line when it hits the right edge of the div, it just keeps going and breaks the element.

I am just wanting to know how to make it line break when it hits the edge spaces provided by user or not.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `word-wrap` CSS property that will force long words to wrap:

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

You might also want to look into [`overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Answer (score -1):

Hmmmm...This is an interesting problem. I'm thinking what I would do would be to implement a JavaScript function that would "read" the length of lines and if a single block of writing is longer than the max length, I would grab a substring of (max length - 1), append a dash (-) to the end of it, add in a line break, and proceed from there.